# Use of Relative Clauses Without Any Corresponding Noun Clause/Phrase

Tags: relative-clauses

Is it correct to use relative clauses that do not modify any noun clauses/phrases? Take this next sentence as an example

> I will let you retake the test, which is more than reasonable.

The relative clause does not refer to the test. Rather, it refers to the *action of retaking*. This gives me pause because I learned that RCs should always have a noun clause/phrase that they modify.

Comment: You have learned wrong. Non-defining relative clauses, the kind with commas, are not modifiers but supplements. They can have virtually any expression as antecedent including whole clauses. In your example, the antecedent of "which" is the preceding clause. Think of it as" R is more than reasonable", where R is interpreted as "my letting you retake the test".